# Aptana Studio 3 - FTP Connection Error (Opening file for read failed)

Tags: ftp, aptana3

I am trying to download files through a FTP connection to my local file system in order to work with it in Aptana Studio 3. But I have a wierd problem. Whenever I try to get files from the server I get this error: "Opening file for read failed"

Very simple but uninformative message. So I looked in the internet. Not many people have this error but a few were talking about a solution which has worked for them. They claim that the source of error is windows firewall and in order to solve need to run this command in comman line (cmd.exe)
"netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp disable"

However this did not solve my problem. Then I have realized that the error is only happening in long downloads. (Downloads with many files, which takes long time).

Then I have observed more carefully. So Aptana is basically first trying to get dates (last modified) of files first to compare with the local ones and then downloads the new files. So there 2 stages (chacking dates and downloading).

If the last stage (downloading) takes longer than ~30 seconds, then I get this error. Does anyone else have this problem? How can I solve this?

Note: it is a passive normal (non secure) ftp connection.

Edit:
In the console one time with this error I have realized that there is a synchronization problem too.

> ftp> MDTM w.jpg
>   213 20090622101257
>   ftp> TYPE I
>   200 Type set to I
>   **ftp> CWD /www/home/images/banner
>
>   200 Type set to I
>
>   ftp> PASV 250
>
>   CWD command successful**

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and **I fixed disabling the Windows Firewall**.
Even when I was allowing all the traffic to AptanaStudio.exe still does not work. Just disabiling all the Firewall it works.

I hope that someone knows what is the program that I have to allow to not just disable all the firewall while I'm using Aptana.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, after having a long research I noticed it was some kind of problem with the "Automatically sync in both directions" option. It looks like Aptana can't handle long projects or the server doesn't like aptana to crawl and read files.

So I just disabled the "Automatically sync in both directions"

1. Right click on the project -> Publish -> Deployment Settings
2. Uncheck "Automatically sync my changes with the remote site" or check "Automatically sync from my machine to the remote site"